# Tree Structure - Move Nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class which looks like this:

```
export default class BasicNode extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            value: '',
            children: []  //Type BasicNode          
        };

        this.addChildNode = this.addChildNode.bind(this);
        this.removeChildNode = this.removeChildNode.bind(this);
    }

    addChildNode() {
        this.setState({
            children: [
                ...this.state.children,
                <BasicNode 
                  passedAddChild={this.addChildNode}
                />
            ]
        });
    }

    removeChildNode(id) {
        this.setState({ 
            children: this.state.children.filter(child => child.props.id != id)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                //formatting for the value
                {this.state.children.map(child => child)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Let's say we have a structure of BasicNodes as follow:

```
NodeA
-- NodeB
-- -- NodeB-1
-- -- -- NodeB-1-1
-- -- NodeB-2
-- NodeC
-- -- NodeC-1
-- -- NodeC-1
```

I would like to move nodes around in the tree:

#### Case 1: Add Child

This is straight forward. Invoke addChildNode.

#### Case 2: Remove child

Invoke removeChildNode.

#### Case 3: Move child NodeB-1-1 to grand parent NodeB

I am focussed on the input in NodeB-1-1 which is a child of NodeB-1, and want to move this node so that it's a child of NodeB (in this . How would I notify NodeB to add a child? I can call passedAddChild but that will only add it to NodeB-1-1's parent.

```
-- NodeB
-- -- NodeB-1
-- -- NodeB-1-1
-- -- NodeB-2
...
```

#### Case 4: Move child NodeB-2 from NodeB -> NodeB-1

```
-- NodeB
-- -- NodeB-1
-- -- -- NodeB-2
...
```

I want to be able to move a node so that it's a child of one of it's siblings.
One thing I was thinking about was to pass in an array of children with props to each node (moving the children array out of the state into props. This will allow me to ask the parent to add a node to a child, but:

1. I won't be able to add children from the node itself. (Not the worst thing, can ask the parent)
2. How would I store the children's children and so on, up the whole tree? This doesn't seem ideal.

#### Notes:

- I'm very new to React so still figuring out a bunch of things all over.
- Please feel free to suggest any changes to my whole approach if you feel that would be more suitable.